# How to match one object array and string array in javascript and produce custom result seperated by commas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-map, array-filter

I have two javascript array, One is Object array and another is string array.

Sample Arrays

```
const arr1 = [{"key": "Jon", "value" : "King"},
              {"key": "Danny", "value" : "Queen"},
              {"key": "Cersei", "value" : "False Queen"},
              {"key": "Tyrion", "value" : "Hand"}]

const arr2 = ["Jon","Tyrion"]
```

I want to console log or print on html output like below. I dont want comma after `hand`.
Required Output

```
King, Hand
```

Please suggest how can it be done using map or filter.
Oneliners are very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to filter by **key** and output by **value**?

Comment: I updated the question. I have the keys in arr2, so i guess by keys

Comment: What have you tried here? Your attempt/google searches will lead to both better responses and better learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point you can use the `filter` function from the prototype `array`.

```js
const filtered = arr1.filter(elem => elem.key=== 'Jon' || elem.key=== 'Tyrion')
```

Alternatively, you can also run more complex checks

```js
const filtered = arr1.filter(elem => {
    return elem.key=== 'Jon' || elem.key=== 'Tyrion'
})
```

More about this is well described at mozilla [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?retiredLocale=de)

##### Update after the question was edited

```js
const filtered = arr1.filter(elem => elem.key=== 'Jon' || elem.key=== 'Tyrion')

console.log(filtered.map(elem => elem.value).join(', '))
```

Comment: `[object Object], [object Object]` is not the output the OP is looking for. You're also hardcoding the names now instead of looking at `arr2`.

Comment: @Cerbrus absolutely correct. The map function must have slipped through. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to filter by **key** and disply the related **value**,then below code snippet is a reference for you

```js
const arr1 = [{"key": "Jon", "value" : "King"},
              {"key": "Danny", "value" : "Queen"},
              {"key": "Cersei", "value" : "False Queen"},
              {"key": "Tyrion", "value" : "Hand"}]

const arr2 = ["Jon","Tyrion"]

let result = arr1.filter(a => arr2.some(b => b == a.key )).map(a => a.value).join(", ")

console.log(result)
```